# Software for simulating a slice of an atmosphere?

Tags: atmosphere, worldbuilding-process, worldbuilding-resources

For my world, I want to simulate a 2d vertical slice of an atmosphere, to test if my assumptions about it are correct. The software needs to support gas compression via gravity, different gasses used in the simulation, obstacles, gas emitters, and visualization of data. I want to observe how does the gasses interact given my setup of a gas-emitting superstructure on a jovian planet (Simplified obviously, assuming that the jovian is pure hydrogen). Does the software that allows something like that and is available for private use exist?

Comment: What do you mean with private use?

Comment: @L.Dutch Probably that it isn't proprietary software that was designed by researchers and isn't publicly available.

Comment: Probably freeware is a better term, then?

Comment: Similar question posed on the earth science stack.   https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/18542/are-there-general-circulation-models-that-can-simulate-the-atmosphere-of-venus   They link some code including a couple of atmosphere models.    If these are not the things you are looking for you could ask your question on that stack or on Planetary science stack with more specifics about how your needs differ from what (for example) the Oxford models provide.

Comment: @L.Dutch
Not necessarily, It just has to be something that an individual can in principle get their hands on.

Comment: @Willk
Well, the main difference is that I ain't exactly looking for a weather simulator. More of an altitude-dependent distribution of gases.

Comment: I mean there's this: http://exoplanet.eu/GCM1D/ (which even has an online version!) but as far as I can tell it's mostly optimized for earth-like atmospheric compositions and terrestrial planets. Generally though, software in this search-field isn't very user friendly as it requires you to know almost enough to write the code yourself about the subject to understand and operate it properly. Personally, if I were in your shoes I'd either say "fuck it, authorial fiat" or if I really, absolutely, *need* scientific credibility, I'd hire someone with a doctorate's to write a scientific paper for me

Answer (score 1):

I recently watched an interesting series of videos on [Fluid Simulations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXs_vkc8hpY) which may be helpful in increasing your understanding of how such software works. It may even answer your question entirely.

In terms of where to find free simulations to test your theory: A quick search on GitHub yielded [WebGL Fluid Simulation](https://github.com/PavelDoGreat/WebGL-Fluid-Simulation) which, if you click on the 'Play here' link presents a nice interface where you can mess around and make some pretty pictures:

[image]

The settings seem to be somewhat basic, but you may be able to figure out what you need by playing around with it for a bit.

Personally, I might be playing with it this afternoon. :D